# Windows Server 2008 R2 CALs and license distribution

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, licensing, cals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

When buying Windows Server 2008 R2 edition, I am offered 5 standard CALs (can be used either device or user based).

So for instance, if I was to buy two Windows 2000 R2 OS, I get a total of 10 CALs.

Can I install all 10 on a licensing manager on one of the two servers? Or do I have to install the 5 CALs on each one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AH - 2008 R2 has ni license manager at all except for TS (Terminal Services) which require separate licenses.

Basically you TRACK licenses in your compliance / IT department. THe old way (paper, integrate into your workflows).

Comment: Great, thank you! After all those years with the crappy license manager they got rid of it and now back to paper just in case it's reported to BSA!